# Загрузчик на C++

Tags: c++

Можно ли на С++ создать загрузчик ( чтобы качал из командной строки )? Как wget в Ubuntu. Что мне надо изучать для этого? Какие операторы или функции? Поделитесь пожалуйста статьями(можно и названия просто, я сам найду про них) которые мне помогут для создания такой программы. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 1. Можно скачать wget для windows и не париться.
2. Можно скачать исходники wget и посмотреть как сделано у них.

Comment: У тебя академический интерес  или практический? Если первое уже ответили, если второе - не надо изобретать велосипеды, есть куча готовых классов и библиотек.

Comment: в программировании, если не изобретать велосипеды, не пойдешь вперед! Я не хочу пользоваться готовыми, понимаешь, тогда я не буду программистом. Мне не нужно готовое, я должен помучаться над чем то, чтобы понять как это работает и что делает каждая строка, лишь так я смогу накопить знания и продвинуться вперед.

Answer (score 1):

1. сокеты
2. протоколы http и ftp, можно со временем ознакомиться с https и ftps.
3. неплохо бы ознакомиться с многопоточным программированием - сам когда-то писал простенькую ftp-качалку, и потоки очень пригодились.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам создавать загрузчик, то почитайте сначала про сокеты Беркли. 
А если с работой в сети уже знакомы, то надо уточнять задачу.
Наконец, познакомьтесь как wget сам общается с серверами с помощью анализаторов трафика.

Comment: нет, работой с сетью не знаком. Что посоветуете прочитать для этого? т.е для работы с сетью?

Comment: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/unix/sockets.xml  для начала ознакомиться с этой статьей. Затем уже искать ответы на конкретные вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

wget и под виндовс есть. Никто не мешает скачать исходники, и дальше по них смотреть. Непонятные функции спрашивать.
Параллельно стоит почитать rfc по протоколам http и ftp, что бы понять, что именно нужно отправлять в сокет, и что читать оттуда.